# If paginated comments don't span to a second page, how do I hide the div wrapper?

Tags: comments, functions, pagination

I have a div wrapper around my comments pagination. I have the comments set to paginate in the Wordpress admin at 10 comments per page. I want to hide the div wrapper if there are less than 10 comments (i.e. the pagination links aren't shown). I can't figure out how to do this. I know how to hide the div wrapper if pagination is turned off altogether, but I don't know how to check to see if the comments don't span to a second page when pagination is turned on. Here is my code:

```
<div class="comment-nav-wrapper">

    <div class="left-cap">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="comment-nav">                   
        <?php paginate_comments_links($args); ?>
    </div> 

    <div class="right-cap">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

I would like to hide the comment-nav-wrapper altogether if the comments don't span to a second page. Is there some sort of Wordpress function for this, or do I need to come up with a bit of custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [comments number function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number) or the more native [get_comments_number function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) and combine it with [the page comments option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) `if ( get_option( page_comments ) == TRUE ) // do stuff`